# Actionscript: Is passing functions through events a good idea?

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript

I have an event class which extends the normal events class so I can pass parameters and have custom events.

I have a message event which I use to display a message to the user, I send an event to trigger this message from many places in my project.

I now need to give the user an option in this message and access the answer in the original class which sent the event that triggered the message.

My solution is to pass a function as a parameter to the event listener, then on click the function in my original class is called.

Is this a good approach?

My other solution was to create more events to handle the various options, but I may end up with many types of events.

Comment: It is called **callback** ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Callback_(computer_programming) ) and it is not a bad idea in general, if you don't forget to dispose it after the function reference is no longer needed.

Comment: Thanks. Thats what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a traditional delegation of concern.  If the original class cares about an event, it should listen for it and react to it.  If you wanted to extend "event" it would traditionally be to have it carry more data (or more descriptive data), not to have it carry a function closure.